# Using JQuery to find if a person is under 18 years of age

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I want to find if the person is less then 18 years old when i enter in the value in the input field. To do this i have created a date input box and created a function. My function does not work properly. What am i doing wrong and how can i make this work?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Birthday Validation</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#DOB").on("change paste keyup", function() {


                $datestring = $(this).val();
                //alert(jQuery.type(Date($datestring)));       

                //$eightYearsAgo = now() - $birthday;
                $birthday = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date()) - Date($datestring);


                if(!birthday.isValid()){
                     alert("INVALID DATE");
                }else if (eightYearsAgo.isAfter(birthday)){
                     alert("18+");
                }else{
                     alert("< 18");
                }

            });
        }); 
    </script>

    </head> 


    <body>

    <input name="DOB" type="date" class="form-control" id="DOB" required  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" onchange="validate(date)"> 


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you'd probably have to set 'between two dates' for this filter

Comment: The browser's development console is telling you that you're trying to use variables you never defined.

Comment: You have not one, but many variables and functions you are referencing that don't exist..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already have this done, you need use the correct `datePicker` features to get it working.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#age").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(value, ui) {
            var current = new Date().getTime(), 
                dateSelect = new Date(value).getTime();
                age = current - dateSelect;
                ageGet = Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25); // age / ms / sec / min / hour / days in a year
            if(ageGet < 18){
                less_than_18(ageGet);
            }else{
                greater_than_18(ageGet);
            }
        },
        yearRange: '1900:+0d',//base year:current year
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        defaultDate: '-18yr',
    }).attr("readonly", "readonly"); //prevent manual changes


    function less_than_18(theAge){
        alert("Failed! your age is less than 18. Age: "+theAge);
    }
    function greater_than_18(theAge){
        alert("Done! your age is greater or equal to 18. Age: "+theAge);
    }
});
```

You can test here: https://jsfiddle.net/h4ppstrf/

Comment: Hi TriForce, Thanks for the response. Just curious on how you got the datepicker feature?